# Wireshark Dissector in Lua

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

First of all, I'm new to Lua altogether, and this is my first attempt at writing a wireshark dissector.

My protocol is straightforward - a 2 byte length field, followed by a string of that length.

When I run the code through the Lua console, everything works as expected.

When the code is added to the Wireshark plugins directory, I get the error

> Lua Error: [string "C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Wireshark..."]:15: calling 'add' on bad self (number expected, got string)

Line 15 corresponds is the `t:add(f_text...` line.

Can anyone explain the discrepancy between the execution methods?

```
do
    local p_multi = Proto("aggregator","Aggregator");

    local f_len = ProtoField.int16("aggregator.length","Length",base.DEC)
    local f_text = ProtoField.string("aggregator.text","Text")

    p_multi.fields = { f_len, f_text }

    local data_dis = Dissector.get("data")

    function p_multi.dissector(buf,pkt,root)
            pkt.cols.protocol = "Aggregator"
            local len = buf(0,2):int()
            local t = root:add(p_multi,buf(0,len+2))
            t:add(f_len,buf(0,2),"Length: " .. buf(0,2):int())
            t:add(f_text,buf(2,len),"Text: " .. buf(2,len):string())
    end

    local tcp_encap_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
    tcp_encap_table:add(4321,p_multi)
end
```

Comment: I'll note that I've used http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/wslua_dissector_example.html and http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors for inspiration.
Are there any good sources of API documentation?

Comment: [Chapter 11](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/wsluarm.html) of the User's Guide is the API documentation for the Lua interface. Sections 11.10, 11.11, and 11.12 are the functional interface. Beyond that, there is not really any documentation to be had.  
It looks to me like your dissector should work as written. Your code shows that you get a reference to the data dissector (`local data_dis = Dissector.get("data")`), but that you don't use it. Is this your complete dissector code? If not, you may be accidentally altering `t` somewhere not shown here.

Comment: It is my complete dissector code, the data_dis is a hang-over from the samples linked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your dissector code is very close to correct, but you're doing extra work that the interface won't accept. If you change your `dissector` function like so,

```
function p_multi.dissector(buf,pkt,root)
        pkt.cols.protocol = "Aggregator"
        local len = buf(0,2):int()
        local t = root:add(p_multi,buf(0,len+2))
        t:add(f_len,buf(0,2)) --let Wireshark do the hard work
        t:add(f_text,buf(2,len)) --you've already defined their labels etc.
end
```

you'll get the desired behavior. The labels "Text" and "Length" are already defined for your fields, so there is no need to provide them again on lines 15 and 16.

Comment: Thank you. I posted this question in a rush before leaving work, and taking the time to think about it more this makes more sense now.

Although, I'm still confused as to why it worked through the Lua console!